# Rspec Factory Girl faker does not accept column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm using RSpec with FactoryGirl and Faker. I have the following error:

```
myrailsexp/spec/factories/contacts.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `first_name' for #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Implicit:0x007fa205b233c0> (NoMethodError)
```

Here is the model app/models/contact.rb:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name

  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true

end
```

spec/models/contact_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Contact, :type => :model do
  it "has a valid factory" do 
    Factory.create(:contact).should be_valid 
  end
  it "is invalid without a first_name" 
  it "is invalid without a last_name" 
  it "returns a contact's full_name as a string"
end
```

spec/factories/contacts.rb

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do
    f.first_name { Faker::Name.first_name } 
    f.last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
  end

end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do
    f.first_name { Faker::Name.first_name } 
    f.last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
  end

end
```

should be

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do |f|
    f.first_name { Faker::Name.first_name } 
    f.last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
  end

end
```

And also this line

```
Factory.create(:contact).should be_valid
```

should be

```
FactoryGirl.create(:contact).should be_valid
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using it as a e.g. form, although it is not.  You are not creating any object there. Use it without the `f`. That is the cause of your error `myrailsexp/spec/factories/contacts.rb:5:in block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined methodfirst_name' for # (NoMethodError)`.

Instead use it like this:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contact do
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name } 
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
  end

end
```

and here use FactoryGirl not Factory.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Contact, :type => :model do
  it "has a valid factory" do 
    FactoryGirl.create(:contact).should be_valid 
  end
  it "is invalid without a first_name" 
  it "is invalid without a last_name" 
  it "returns a contact's full_name as a string"
end
```